# How can I concatenate rows into column names?

Tags: r, dplyr

so I have a dataframe imported from excel that looks something like this:

| X1 | A | A | A | A | B | B | B | B | B | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Region | 2001 | 2001 | 2002 | 2002 | 2001 | 2001 | 2002 | 2002 | 2003 | 2003 |
| City | Home | Work | Home | Work | Home | Work | Home | Work | Home | Work |
| City1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| City2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| City3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

I want to turn it into something that looks like this:

| X1RegionCity | A2001Home | A2001Work | A2002Home | A2002Work | B2001Home | B2001Work | B2002Home | B2002Work | B2003Home | B2003Work |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| City2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| City3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

How can I combine three first rows into the column name? I eventually plan to later turn this into a long DF with the year, and Home/Work as a separate column. Is there a way to do this entirely in R, with or without dplyr? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code to reproduce your test dataset with `dput()`? It will be easier to reproduce your example and to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste0`:

```r
colnames(df) <- paste0(colnames(df), df[1, ], df[2, ])
df <- df[-c(1, 2), ]
```

```r
  X1RegionCity A2001Home A2001Work A2002Home A2002Work B2001Home B2001Work B2002Home B2002Work B2003Home B2003Work
3        City1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
4        City2         2         2         2         2         2         2         2         2         2         2
5        City3         3         3         3         3         3         3         3         3         3         3
```